# Java array matrix number

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

This is the code that i made

```
class Printsqu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = { { 1,5,9,13 }, { 2,6,10,14 }, { 3,7,11,15 },
                { 4,8,12,16 }, };

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print( array[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

the output should be

```
  1  5  9 13
  2  6 10 14
  3  7 11 15
  4  8 12 16
```

this but it prints out

```
1593
261014
371115
481216
```

So I added \t between them but it jumps too much.

Is there any way to fix this?

funny thing is that the space between numbers are different

I would grateful if you guys add details about code and explanations thanks.

Comment: array's first line contain 3 instead of 13. `{1, 5, 9, 13}`

Comment: use this System.out.print( array[i][j] +" \t");

Comment: \t jumps too much in the code it's useless

Comment: @WJ please check my answer. Thanks

Comment: @Omore got error when I tried yours...

Comment: tell me about your error it's working fine on my IDE.

Comment: wait it works thangks my bad

Comment: @WJ your welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array = { { 1,5,9,13 }, { 2,6,10,14 }, { 3,7,11,15 },
            { 4,8,12,16 }, };

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {

            System.out.printf("%2d ", array[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the value of `WIDTH` with whatever number of characters you want to give for one number.

```
class Printsqu {
  public static final int WIDTH = 3;
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int[][] array = { { 1,5,9,13 }, { 2,6,10,14 }, { 3,7,11,15 },
                { 4,8,12,16 }, };

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%"+WIDTH+"d", array[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
  }
}
```